# how to enforce resource generation when having deep cross-reference

Tags: xtext

I just started using `Xtext` a couple of months ago.
I have the following grammar:

```
grammar org.example.entities.Entities with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate entities "http://www.example.org/entities/Entities"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
import "http: //www. eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes"

Model: entities += Entity | Composite;

Entity:
  'entity' name = ID ('extends' superType=[Entity])? '{'
    attributes += Attribute*
    strings += StringAttr*
  '}'
;

StringAttr: 'string' name=ID;
Attribute:
  type=[Entity] array?=('[]')? name=ID ';';

EntityField:
    'field' field=[Entity];
```

Lets say I have 3 files:

### file `first.entities`:

```
entity entity1 {
  string s
}
```

### file `second.entities`:

```
entity entity2 extends entity1 {
  string s2
}
```

### file `third.entities`:

```
entity entity3 extends entity2 {
  string s3
}
```

when I modify `entity1`, for example add `string myString` to it, then the `doGenerate(..)` method is invoked twice - for `first.entities` and for `second.entities` due to the cross reference between `entity2` and `entity1`, but `third.entity` resouce is not passed to `doGenerate(..)`.

how can I trigger a change event across the entire dependency tree?

Thanks